# Reusing Z3 as a library jar in Java

Tags: java, scala, jar, z3

Currently I am working on a tool for my masterthesis which uses Z3. I have chosen to use the Java bindings within my Scala project. Now I would like to create a distributable jar which may be used both standalone and by other projects. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a simple way to do it as the com.microsoft.z3.jar uses native libraries such as libz3.{so,dylib,lib,dll}.

Normally, native libraries have to be linked by adding the `-Djava.library.path=...` flag specifying where the native libraries may be found.

I have been looking at SBT pack, assembly and one-jar but none of these packaging tools seem to allow reuse by other projects and link the native libraries automatically; also when my project is used as a library.

Ideally, the result is a .jar where the native libraries are included and Java knows where to find them (java.library.path) without the user having the specify anything. The .jar itself may be executed or imported as a library by another project.

Would I have to fallback to a situation where the flag `-Djava.library.path=...` has to be included for each project using Z3?

Any suggestions are more than welcome! Thanks!

Comment: (1) I *think* sbt-assembly can be configured to package arbitrary files into the jar file it creates; the docs hopefully know more (2) If your project can be used as a standalone application, shipping it with shell/batch files that set `-Djava.library.path` might be a solution

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff You are absolutely right. Except java.library.path cannot give a path to something in the .jar. Also, I noticed you also have to set an environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for shared objects / native libraries to find each other. 

Thank you very much for thinking with me ;)